# How to delete particular no of elements from array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have collection as below

```
"_id" : "PS8720_18",
    "AlertID" : "18",
    "Status" : "ACTIVE",
    "triggerHistory" : [ 
        {"triggerId" : "1535081507421"}, 
        {"triggerId" : "1535105196735"}, 
        {"triggerId" : "1535341330335"}, 
        {"triggerId" : "1535364578821"}
 ]
```

I want to delete all element and just want keep last two entries in the array. Each document has different no of elements in array. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check with the following Query

```
db.getCollection('youtablename').update({}, {
 $push: {
  triggerHistory: {
     $each: [ ],
     $slice: -2
  }
}},{multi:true})
```

Hope it Helps !!